# Display of a large amount of data in a Canvas with a Scrollbar

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm having a problem trying to display a large table in tkinter.

First, I tried to display all label at once in the canvas, but over few hundred rows, the program shut down. So I tried to create a scrollable canvas that updates everytime I scroll: I collect the position of the scrollbar and depending on the position of it, I display the 10 values corresponding.

But I can't get this code working. For now it only displays a black background with the scrollbar on the right.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.x = []
        for i in range(1, 1000):
            self.x.append(i)
        self.parent = parent 
        self.mainFrame =  Frame(self.parent)
        self.mainFrame.pack()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.mainFrame, width = 200, height = 500, bg = "black")
        self.canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.scroll = Scrollbar(self.mainFrame, orient = VERTICAL, command = self.update)
        self.scroll.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.scroll.set)
        self.tabCursor = 0
        self.scrollPosition = self.scroll.get()

    def update(self):
        self.tabCursor = round(self.scrollPosition[0]*len(self.x))
        if ((len(self.x) - self.tabCursor) < 10):
            self.tabCursor = len(self.x) - 10
        for i in range(0, 10): #display 10 values
            label = Label(self.canvas, text = str(self.x[tabCursor + i]), width = 50)
            label.grid(column = 0, row = i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

EDIT : 
I finally had time to implement your answer. It looks fine but I can't get the scrollbar working and i don't know why.

```
class TableauDeDonnees(object):
    "Tableau de données -- Onglet Tableau de données"
    def __init__(self, data, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.data = data
        print(self.data[0], self.data[1])
        print(len(self.data[0]), len(self.data[1]))
        self.labels = []
        self.navigationFrame = Frame(self.parent)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.parent, bg = "black", width = 200, height = 500)
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.canvas)
        self.navigationFrame.pack()
        print(len(data))
        for row in range(50):
            for column in range(len(data)):
                self.labels.append(Label(self.canvas, text = str(data[column][row])))
        for i in range(len(self.labels)):
            self.labels[i].grid(row = i // 2, column = i % 2, sticky = NSEW)
        self.boutonRetour = Button(self.navigationFrame, text = "Retour", command = lambda: self.move(-2))
        self.quickNav = Entry(self.navigationFrame, width = 3)
        self.quickNav.bind('<Return>', lambda x: self.move(self.quickNav.get()))
        self.boutonSuivant = Button(self.navigationFrame, text = "Suivant", command = lambda: self.move(0))

        temp  = divmod(len(data[0]), len(self.labels) // 2)
        self.pages = temp[0] + (1 if temp[1] else 0)

        self.position = Label(self.navigationFrame, text='Page 1 sur ' + str(self.pages))
        self.pageCourante = 1

        self.boutonRetour.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.quickNav.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.boutonSuivant.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
        self.position.grid(row = 0, column = 3)

        self.scroll = Scrollbar(self.parent, orient = VERTICAL, command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.scroll.set)
        self.scroll.pack(side = RIGHT, fill='y')
        self.canvas.pack(side = LEFT, fill = 'both')

        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window = self.mainFrame, anchor = "nw", tags = "frame")
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.scroll.set)
        self.mainFrame.bind("<Configure>", self.update)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def update(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def move(self, direction):
        if (self.pageCourante == 1 and direction == -2) or (self.pageCourante == self.pages and direction == 0):
            return
        if direction in (-2, 0):
            self.pageCourante += direction + 1
        else:
            try:
                temp = int(direction)
                if temp not in range(1, self.pages + 1):
                    return
            except ValueError:
                return
            else:
                self.pageCourante = temp
        for i in range(len(self.labels)):
            try:
                location = str(self.data[i % 2][len(self.labels)*(self.pageCourante - 1) + i])
            except IndexError:
                location = ''
            self.labels[i].config(text = location)
        self.position.config(text = 'Page ' + str(self.pageCourante) + ' sur ' + str(self.pages))
```

I don't understand why the scrollbar isn't working properly. Note, that my parent is a notebook. 
Also, there is a problem with the number of items displayed. The number of pages is right but it seems it displays more than it should cause last pages are empty and the last values displayed seems right.

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrollbar doesn't work by continuously creating new widgets ad infinitum. You were also missing some key parts - unfortunately, `Scrollbar` isn't as straightforward as most `tkinter` widgets.

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent 
        self.canvas =  Canvas(self.parent, bg='black', width = 200, height = 500)
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.canvas)
        self.scroll = Scrollbar(self.parent, orient = VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both')
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.mainFrame, anchor="nw", tags="frame")

        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.scroll.set)
        self.mainFrame.bind("<Configure>", self.update)        
        self.x = []
        for i in range(1000):
            self.x.append(Label(self.mainFrame, text=str(i)))
            self.x[i].grid()

    def update(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

If you'd like to show only a few at a time and provide a forum-like interface, you can use `Button`s to navigate between pages. This example allows the user to navigate with Back and Forward buttons, as well as by entering a page number in the box and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.x = list(range(1000))
        self.labels = []
        self.parent = parent
        self.navigation_frame = Frame(self.parent)
        self.canvas =  Canvas(self.parent, bg='black', width = 200, height = 500)
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.canvas)
        self.navigation_frame.pack()
        for i in range(100):
            self.labels.append(Label(self.mainFrame, text=str(i)))
            self.labels[i].grid()
        self.back_button = Button(self.navigation_frame, text='Back', command=lambda: self.move(-2))
        self.quick_nav = Entry(self.navigation_frame, width=3)
        self.quick_nav.bind('<Return>', lambda x: self.move(self.quick_nav.get()))
        self.forward_button = Button(self.navigation_frame, text='Forward', command=lambda: self.move(0))

        temp = divmod(len(self.x), len(self.labels))
        self.pages = temp[0] + (1 if temp[1] else 0)

        self.you_are_here = Label(self.navigation_frame, text='Page 1 of ' + str(self.pages))
        self.current_page = 1
        self.back_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.quick_nav.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.forward_button.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.you_are_here.grid(row=0, column=3)
        self.scroll = Scrollbar(self.parent, orient = VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both')
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.mainFrame, anchor="nw", tags="frame")

        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.scroll.set)
        self.mainFrame.bind("<Configure>", self.update)   

    def update(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def move(self, direction):
        if (self.current_page == 1 and direction == -2) or (self.current_page == self.pages and direction == 0):
            return
        if direction in (-2, 0):
            self.current_page += direction + 1
        else:
            try:
                temp = int(direction)
                if temp not in range(1, self.pages+1):
                    return
            except ValueError:
                return
            else:
                self.current_page = temp
        for i in range(len(self.labels)):
            try:
                location = str(self.x[len(self.labels)*(self.current_page - 1) + i])
            except IndexError:
                location = ''
            self.labels[i].config(text=location)
        self.you_are_here.config(text='Page ' + str(self.current_page) + ' of ' + str(self.pages))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's supposed to create new widgets all the time, overwriting the reference?

Comment: Yeah that what it was supposed to be. The problem I have is i have a big table to display (7000 rows, 2 columns) and I'm afraid it can be slow. So was trying to "blit" 20 values each time on a canvas.
Edit : I just tried your solution from 1 to 7000 and it takes some seconds to display.
Do you have any idea how I could update the grid each time? 
Thank you very much for your code though it helps me understanding this widget better

Comment: In that case, how about displaying only a small number of entries, like 100, and adding some kind of navigation to different pages, similar to how most forum software works?

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea, i thought about a tab first because i wanted the data to be copy-pastable but then i chose to export them in a .csv file instead so maybe your idea is good in my scenario ill think about it

Comment: I forgot to ask, could you explain me this line i don't understand:
        self.mainFrame.bind("<Configure>", self.update)

Comment: `self.mainFrame.bind("<Configure>", self.update)` binds `self.update` to whenever `self.mainFrame` sees a `<Configure>` event (the frame was configured), in the same way that something like `self.parent.bind("<Return>", self.go)` would bind `self.go` to whenever `self.parent` sees a `<Return>` event (user pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> within the program).

Comment: @AlexisDurieux, I've edited the answer to include page navigation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll look at that more precisely in the morning !